# Dev vs test vary in twig's format_currency output

Tags: symfony, twig

On my local dev environment, I use the twig filter `|format_currency("USD", {fraction_digit: 0})` to ensure the output of the currency shows like so: "$2" - however, on my test environment (via server deployment), the dollar output seems to ignore the `fraction_digit` parameter because it shows the money like so: "$2.00."

Why is this varying? Both environments have all the composer packages installed. Is this a configuration thing, and am I missing something?

I'm using Symfony 5.X.

Comment: Is `IntlExtension` installed?

Comment: It is. I checked on my test server.

Comment: Also not sure why formats differ from dev to test. That’s a bizarre interaction I’ve never seen.

Comment: Maybe there’s a configuration thing I’m missing?

Comment: @Majo0od Did you manage to sort this out? I've got the exact same issue.

Comment: Nope, I haven't been able to figure this out.